# inittab not restarting service after service crash in Red Hat 6.7

Tags: linux, rhel, init, chkconfig

NOTE: I am running Red Hat 6.7

I have a service that is configured with the Linux init system to start a process as a service when the machine boots. This was done by doing this one-time configuration from the command line:

```
ln -snf /home/me/bin/my_service /etc/init.d/my_service
chkconfig --add my_service
chkconfig --level 235 my_service on
```

When the OS reboots, the service starts as expected.

I ALSO need the service to be restarted if the service (my_service) crashes. From what I've read, all I need to do is add an entry to /etc/inittab that looks like this:

mysvc:235:respawn:/home/me/bin/my_service_starter

Where my_service_starter looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/me/bin/my_service start
```

The my_service script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
"/usr/java/bin/java" /home/me/bin/my_service.jar start
```

My understanding is that when the init system detects that my_service is not running, it will attempt to restart it by running "my_service_starter".

However this does not seem to be working. i.e. the service does not start when the OS reboots.

I need to understand how to tell the Linux init system to restart my service when the service crashes.

Comment: I updated the post to try to clarify things a bit more. "does not seem to be working" means that the service does not start when the OS boots. The my_service script simply runs a java jar file in a jvm (see updated post for details).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RedHat 6 uses *upstart* as the init system.

At the very beginning of the provided `inittab` files are the lines:

```
# inittab is only used by upstart for the default runlevel.
#
# ADDING OTHER CONFIGURATION HERE WILL HAVE NO EFFECT ON YOUR SYSTEM.
```

You need to create a proper `init` definition in `/etc/init`  (note: **NOT** `/etc/init.d`).

eg (but may need debugging) `/etc/init/myservice`

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [S016]

respawn
exec /home/me/bin/my_service_starter
```

Comment: after my post I came across the information on RHEL 's Web site indicating RHEL v 6 uses upstart. Your suggested solution works.